# how to proof the Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left\lvert \frac{1}{(n+1)^x}-\frac{1}{n^x} \right\rvert$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $x>0$ be a positive real number and the series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left\lvert \frac{1}{(n+1)^x}-\frac{1}{n^x} \right\rvert$$
How can I proof that it is convergent?

Thanks

Comment: The terms are negative so the absolute value is $1/n^x-1/(n+1)^x$ and the partial sum telescopes so the sum is $1$

Comment: @marwalix thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(t)=\frac1{t^x}$. Then by the Lagrange MVT, one has
$$ f(t+1)-f(t)=f'(\xi)=-\frac{x}{\xi^{x+1}},\xi\in(t,t+1) $$
and hence
$$ \bigg|\frac{1}{(n+1)^x}-\frac1{n^x}\bigg|=|f(n+1)-f(n)|=f'(\xi)=\bigg|\frac{x}{\xi^{x+1}}\bigg|\le \frac{x}{n^{x+1}},\xi\in(n,n+1). $$
Since $x>0$, one has that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x}{n^{x+1}}$ converges, which implies that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\bigg|\frac{1}{(n+1)^x}-\frac1{n^x}\bigg|$ conerges.